# Cannot import coffee-script file into application.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I am facing a problem that is too hard to fix. I am building a Rails application, I created a coffee-script file named **mypage.coffee**. Then, I embedded this file into application.js file. The error occurred! I open Dev Tool and in the Console window, it said:

```
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/coffeescript". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

It's strange!
[This is the tree folder of my project, it helps you understand my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6H4y.png)

If you know what happened to me, please help me resolve it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Coffeescript has to be transpiled to JavaScript before your JavaScript module can import it.